# Permission Denied to modify tasks and cpu.shares

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cgroups, container

As an experiment I was trying to add some processes in `tasks` and modify some `cpu.shares`. However I get Permission denied if I try to run commands like

I created a folder `test` inside of `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu`

```
$ sudo -s
$whoami
root

$ echo 2472 > tasks
-bash: tasks: Permission denied

$sudo echo 10 > cpu.shares
-bash: cpu.shares: Permission denied
```

Also, an ls of the folder does not show these 2 files. (Because no PIDs in the task file??)

Also, if I try to delete the `test` folder, I cant. I get the error

```
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.events': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/io.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.max.descendants': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cpu.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/memory.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cpu.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.type': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.threads': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.kill': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.freeze': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.controllers': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.subtree_control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.max.depth': Operation not permitted
```

But why am I not able to edit these files or delete this created folder?
I tried running the commands as a root user

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1

I can also see group.controllers..... Is it something to do with cgroupv2?

Update cgroupv2 uses `cgroup.procs` `cpu.max` and `cpuset.cpus`. These files were editable.
It seems like anytime I try to create a new file (for eg `cpu.shares`) in this folder, the permission is denied.
Sticky Bits??

Comment: I suspect it might have to do with ACL, but that's way above my pay-grade, so I don't want to suggest anything.

Comment: since you are using /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu then probably you are using cgroup v1. it might be the cpu controller is busy being mounted in cgroup v2? if you have cgroup v2 enabled you should find cgroup.controllers file with the available controllers in v2. in this case, you will find your cgroup dir right under /sys/fs/cgroup/<test:in this example>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing `rm` with the `-rf` flags (`rm -rf test`)? If that doesn't work, maybe `rmdir test` works.

Comment: nope none of these work weirdly